# Using environment variable for 'recipients:' in Jenkins Pipeline Mailer

Tags: email, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a list of email ids in a Jenkins environment variable(emailsdl) and trying to use this for `recipients:` in Jenkins Pipeline Mailer as below:

```
mail (to: 'Mailer', recipients: '${env.emailsdl}',
 subject: "Job '${env.JOB_NAME}' (${env.BUILD_NUMBER}) is waiting for input",
 body: "Please go to ${env.BUILD_URL}.")
```

With the above code I am not receiving email and receiving an error:

> Email not sent. No recipients of any kind specified ('to', 'cc', 'bcc').

But when I replace `${env.emailsdl}` with real email(xyxyx@foo.com) then it does trigger an email. I even tried  `env['emailsdl']` and it didn't work.

Is there a way I can pass environment variable for recipients in this case?

Comment: If you add `echo env.emailsdl` line to the script does is print the correct value?

Comment: @Gergely: Your suggestion helped me resolving my issue. The problem is that I have a local environment variable which was assigned with a value from other global environment variable: `globalVar = xyxyx@foo.com` and `emailsdl=${globalVar}` is in job's local properties. Now I am calling this `emailsdl` in pipeline script. This has been resolved by: `env.((env.emailsdl).replaceAll("\$", ""))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Gergely: Your suggestion helped me resolving my issue. The problem is that I have a local environment variable which was assigned with a value from other global environment variable: `globalVar = xyxyx@foo.com` and `emailsdl=${globalVar}` is in job's local properties. Now I am calling this `emailsdl` in pipeline script. This has been resolved by:

```
env.((env.emailsdl).replaceAll("\$", ""))
```

Comment: Could you accept your answer then so this question does not remain unanswered?

Answer (score 2):

In groovy if you use single quoted string it will not be interpolated, which means that in the string `'${env.emailsdl}'` the variable `env.emailsdl` will not be replaced. You need to use double quoted string: `"${env.emailsdl}"`